# How to get javascript variable after login with jsoup Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, webview, jsoup

I´m building an android app. First I´m log in into a website

```
res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/action=")
                    .data("username", "id", "password", "password")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();


            doc = res.parse();

            sessionId = res.cookie("PHPSESSID");
```

Then I load the next site:

```
 doc3 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/site2")
                    .cookie("PHPSESSID", sessionId)
                    .get();
```

but on site2 I need to get the Javascript array:

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var classes = ["ADA","AOP1A"]
</script>
```

I know Jsoup only parse Html. How can i get this variable? It´s my first Android project
thank you

Comment: You can get the contents of that script tag with Jsoup, and then you can use a regex to actually extract the desired data from the script, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the nature of the website you are parsing, but generally speaking you can't do it with Jsoup.

I would suggest you use a headless browser that supports JavaScript, such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) or [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)!

Comment: OP says it's an Android project, so Selenium is not an option (it's desktop only !), and it's extremely hard (almost impossible) to get HtmlUnit to work on Android. It also seems that OP does not want to actually run the script, but just to extract some data from it. A regex would work here.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you are right, and after some searching there seems to be selenium for android (Selendroid, not sure if this is the same company behind Selenium). But yes I would agree with you and OP may be able to do so, which is why I said it "depends on the nature of the website". If the variable in question is populated/generated by Javascript, then no luck; but if it's static, then yes surely regex would work!

Comment: Thank you both. Could someone please help me find the right regex?      `scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");`

Comment: I need an output like:  ADA AOP1A

Comment: please give us a sample html file that you are trying to parse, that way it's easier for us to work out the regex, or the corresponding jsoup query